# How to disable Eclipse (3.3.2) warning: Access to enclosing constructor... is emulated by a synthetic accessor method

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I work on a large project and want to disable the Eclipse compiler warning stating:

> Access to enclosing constructor ... is emulated by a synthetic accessor method. Increasing its visibility will improve your performance

Eclipse version 3.3.2

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the Window–Preferences menu, browse to the Java–Errors/Warnings panel. Expand the "Code style" settings, and set the "Access to a non-accessible member of an enclosing type:" option to "Ignore".

Comment: This option seems to be broader than the optimization in the message above. I want to have warnings for accessing non-accessible members of an enclosing type but not see the performance messages.

Comment: There is only one warning, the one that mentions performance. You can't keep it and get rid of it.

Comment: Unfortunately, even when setting that flag to "Ignore" one still gets these warnings: "Access to enclosing constructor ... is emulated by a synthetic accessor method". Is there a way to silence these as well? I get thousands of these in automatically generated code so I have no choice other than to ignore them. So, I don't even want to *see* them!

Comment: @mmo This option does eliminate the warning from constructors too, in my environment. If you get different results, consider opening a new question, referencing this, with a code sample and more specifics about your Eclipse version.

Comment: @erickson: I am using Eclipse version: 2019-03 (4.11.0) / Build id: 20190314-1200. And I can only say that in the application we are building I still see LOTS of "Access to enclosing constructor ..." warnings albeit having changed 
the "Access to a non-accessible member of an enclosing type:" option to "Ignore". I changed that in Eclipse's global options (as described above) and I don't use project specific settings.